# Can the telephone signals be tapped by an intruder?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electronics, electrical-engineering, signal-processing

I have a doubt.

There are *lots* of telecommunication signals moving across the world, at the same time.

For example, take the case of mobile phone calls.

Millions of speech signals are propagating as em waves, *simultaneously.*

How does the network operators avoid overlap of the signals ?

I mean, isn't that too complicated?

Also, tell me if it is possible for an intruder to *tap* the signals and leak its content without the knowledge of the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern telephone signals propagate as digital packets (sets of data with a particular size). Each packet has specific parameters that contain the source and destination addresses. Based on these parameters, the packets are routed properly and automatically by the network equipment.

Tapping to signals is indeed possible. Whether or not this would leak the content depends on encryption. I believe, all modern cell signals are encrypted, so chances of listening to a cell conversation without spy level tools and techniques are slim. Perhaps tapping to a landline may leak the content, but I will defer to the experts on the specifics.

Comment: Prior to digital phones, you could easily (1) buy scanners which could eavesdrop.  Unscrupulous journalists would sometimes do it.  Today, they hack voicemail instead which suggests that their behaviour has not improved but the technology has. (1) Probably dependent on the location but it was easy here in the UK.

Comment: @badjohn: This is exactly what Nixon went down for in the US ;)